# What are the contents of logcat file?

Tags: android, logcat

I have to parse the logcat output for my android application.So i wanted to know logcat content. I surfed a lot but i don't a proper answer. what are the logcat contents and when the system writes the logcat file?

Thanks
Pushpa

Answer (score 0):

There's no api that I know of to read the logcat directly into your program. The easiest thing to do is to run `logcat` externally from your app and collect the results. One example of how to do that is [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-random/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Logcat) (see [LogcatProcessor.java](http://code.google.com/p/android-random/source/browse/trunk/Logcat/src/org/devtcg/tools/logcat/LogcatProcessor.java)). Another, more elaborate, version is [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-log-collector/) (see [SendLogActivity.java](http://code.google.com/p/android-log-collector/source/browse/trunk/android-log-collector/src/com/xtralogic/android/logcollector/SendLogActivity.java)).

You will need this line in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```